# How to close notification panel without AccessibilityService in Android 12?

Tags: android, android-12

I'm looking for a way to close a notification panel after the user pressed some button in my notification. Currently, I'm doing it like that:

```
sendBroadcast(Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS))
```

But, this way is deprecated on Android 12 and the official recommendation is to use `GLOBAL_ACTION_DISMISS_NOTIFICATION_SHADE` action from `AccessibilityService`.

Is there any way to do it somehow without `AccessibilityService`?

Comment: Google seems to think the panel will close automatically when startActivity is called, but it definitely does not and is frustrating

Comment: Raise an issue with https://issuetracker.google.com/

Comment: Any progress on it ? I need same thing. @VolodymyrH

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: in my case, i tried  calling the startActivity from BroadcastReceiver, did you find any solution on this?

Comment: @NinadSawant, no. And you can't call startActivity from there since Android 12 - it will crash.

Comment: @VolodymyrH is there any alternate solution for that?

Comment: @NinadSawant, for closing dialogs - no, new Google policy, such approach may break accessibility. For start activity from background - maybe workmanager + notification